# How To give Unique Id's To Instantiated Objects In Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was looking around for quite some time to find the best way to give instantiated objects unique id's in Unity. I found tons of ways but none worked for the game I am making.
I figured out my own way to do this and thought I would share!

This is for my UI at main menu. I am instantiating buttons based on how many sprites I have in my resources folder. I needed each button to change the player skin to a different sprite so they needed unique ids.

Attached this script to my button prefab:

```
    public class ShopButtons : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int[] buttonArray = new int[] {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    public static int arIndex = 0;

    public int buttonID;


    void Start()
        {
            if (buttonArray[arIndex] == 0)
            {
                buttonID = arIndex;
                buttonArray[arIndex] = 1;
            }
             arIndex++;
         }
}
```

I am a beginner so tips are appreciated. This is my first time using arrays and it worked wonders for my project!

Comment: Just use `Guid`s, far easier.

Comment: I didn't know those existed thanks for the tip!

Comment: Probably also a good idea to set the value in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the [`Guid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid?view=netframework-4.7.2) type instead. They are effectively guaranteed to be unique and are easily created by the framework for you. Also, it would likely be best to set the ID in the constructor. For example:

```
public class ShopButtons : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Guid UniqueId { get; }

    public ShopButtons() 
    {
        UniqueId = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    //etc...
}
```

If you are going to use this concept across multiple types, you could even abstract that away into a base class, for example:

```
public abstract class MonoBehaviourWithId : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Guid UniqueId { get; }

    public MonoBehaviourWithId() 
    {
        UniqueId = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

Which would make your `ShopButtons` class look much simpler:

```
public class ShopButtons : MonoBehaviourWithId
{
    //etc...
}
```

Comment: You can initialise these inline: `public Guid UniqueId { get; } = Guid.NewGuid()`

Comment: Yes, I prefer not to.

Comment: I gathered: I added the comment for the benefit of the OP, who may prefer to.